# Can an assertion guard clause also return a value?

Tags: typescript

I want to make an `asserts` style guard clause that can also return a value.  Is this possible?  Here's my dream.

```
// this return type gives a compiler error
export function assertString(input: any): ((asserts input is string) & string) {
    if (typeof input != "string") throw "Expected string, got " + input;
    return input;
}
```

It could be used flexibly.

```
function getLength(arg: any) {
    assertString(arg);
    return arg.length;
}

// but also
function getLength2(arg: any) {
    return assertString(arg).length;
}
```

Is this possible in typescript?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PQKjAIFsEMGsFNwBcAWBLAzuA7gewE6w5qq4CuS4ABtAHYCeV40ARmRomCMALABQ-eAA8ADgUoAzMrQDGSNLlrMMHfEgDKSfGloBzABQ6RFAFzMGASjPQV8NViMVwmcBi07d4AN79wf5xLg+kj0IvC4gY6UAIQAvOAARG7aegkWyCj4uNiJAKKi8HLwACau7noANOC6uJQJ4ADUzrTGSADcvv748Ehk+EqgOCjQSAD8fijZ49z8AL78-KAQxbjgtLXgMsN6iHT0m7jFiCzwADbZGS6nOpxgvAJ8UrLyitU9ADLweqj60Pi61ks3k6fhsqg05QMf10Fg6fH84G6vX6zH+ADpTl9dKg4fMHsBgOA2JRoKcMLh+E85AolLoPljUAAmX7-QH0dI+eFdHp9JRguwQlJQ-4WDEMlC4-hAA

Answer (score 2):

As of today (April 15 2020) the answer is no.

There is a GitHub issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34636

Until this issue is resolved you can use a conditional return type like so:

```
function assertString<T>(input: T): T extends string ? string : never {
    if (typeof input !== "string") throw "Expected string, got " + input;
    return (input as any);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, the generic hack isn't a complete solution.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoGUpYxgDmAPACoB8AFEQA4hQBci5AlC+YhgB5QZgAJqkSoCRYogD8o8SUQswGAG7ZEAbwCwAKER7EMYImpQAnnQxwj9RogCEAXgeIARGMIkXbRFAAWWOAB3VwBRHgtoDEFZD2IAGkRiOChXRABqAzAGKABuHX1ELAwoECwkWizbNBQwUzY87QBfHR1QSFgEROKAGQFiP2pkLGIWdwlEAB9EMBAAWwAjbG8tXX00TBx8WMHh+vz9IpKylGGAOgAbPr8G5u0gA